# Why does strong_parameters not work when I upgrade from Rails 3 to Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following:

```
class PhotoLibrariesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @photo_library = PhotoLibrary.new(photo_library_params)

    if @photo_library.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to photo_libraries_path }
        format.js
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Photo Library not created successfully'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @photo_library = PhotoLibrary.new
  end

  def index
    @photo_libraries = PhotoLibrary.all
  end

  private

  def photo_library_params
    params.require(:photo_library).permit( :title )
  end
end
```

This always results in:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for PhotoLibrary: title
    app/controllers/photo_libraries_controller.rb:35:in `create'
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Why doesn't strong_parameters seem to be working?

Comment: did you remove attr_accessible from photo_library?

Comment: Yes, it is not in the model...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove or set to false the following config in `config/application.rb`

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```